# Our server infrastructure has grown, needing way to administer passwords for Ubuntu environments

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts

I am not a server admin, but our current server administrator left. So it has temporarily fallen on me to look after things. Our systems are currently protected by public/private keys. But when doing some investigation I found the only access is through this key. I don't believe there are any secondary accounts that could be accessed. The root has been locked down. This troubles me because if for any reason the key failed/expired we would be locked out. As I said I am not a server admin, but I figured we would at least need another accessible account that is not root, possibly with sudo permissions.

Now comes the problem, we have around 30 Ubuntu primarily web servers, and managing all of those passwords seems like a chore. I don't wish to go in and create accounts just yet. I need advice on the best way to configure access to 30+ (and growing) servers.

What is the best way to secure the environment, with growth in mind? Do I just need to manually configure all of those accounts, with individual passwords? Or should we be thinking about using a directory service? If yes, what would you recommend for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things:

> Our systems are currently protected by public/private keys. But when doing some investigation I found the only access is through this key.

This reads like there is shared admin account and a shared ssh key to remote log on to that account.

In general you want administrators (and all users really) to log in with their own account and their own keys. And then they can elevate their privileges with `sudo` and their own personal passwords.

When a person leaves your organisation you can then lock/delete their personal account and you're done.

With shared accounts the process becomes increasingly more complicated, because you should change the password of all shared accounts everywhere and the more there are, the more likely you'll miss one or something breaks.

> root has been locked down. This troubles me because if for any reason the key failed/expired we would be locked out.

Almost universally all security guidelines require that ***remote root access*** should be disabled.  Root login via the console is typically allowed, but requires the root password to be known.

As [already suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/1156044/37681) generate a list of strong root passwords, ideally one for each system, print that list and stick it in the office safe for break glass events. (When you need to access the remote console.)

Make SHA512 encrypted hashes of those passwords and use those encrypted passwords to set the root passwords on your systems (via your configuration management automation) to prevent handling of clear text passwords.

Conventional ssh key pairs don't expire by the way.

> Now comes the problem, we have around 30 Ubuntu primarily web servers, and managing all of those passwords seems like a chore. I don't wish to go in and create accounts just yet. I need advice on the best way to configure access to 30+ (and growing) servers.

With 30 servers and expecting more you should consider a form of centralised and automated configuration management.

That will make it much easier:

- to provision access for each team member/ employee / sysadmin with a personal account and their ssh key-pair
- to provision (group based) `sudo` privileges for every team member/ employee / sysadmin
- do updates
- re-deploy the correct configuration for testing, horizontal scaling, disaster recovery etc.

With proper automated configuration management you can avoid a centralized user directory and provision local user accounts for all your admins and staff.

That might be less complicated in the short term.

But if you want to enforce regular password rotation, and need to ensure that everybody uses strong passwords a central user directory quickly becomes the better solution.

If you already have a central user directory, Microsoft Active Directory for example, it is almost always better to integrate with that, than to set up a separate user directory for the management of your Linux servers.

Comment: I have done some googling of "centralised and automated configuration management" SAAS. But not really sure what I am looking at. Do you have any suggestions, pointers, as to services that may work for us?

Comment: As usual wikipedia has a list of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software which gives an idea of possible solutions. I don't knwo what is best for you, but I have used Ansible, Puppet, Chef, cfengine, Rudder, Spacewalk and would recommend any over manual check lists and installation manuals. They all come with a learning curve and will take time to see return on investment but then that is what allows single digit sized teams to  manage an infrastructure with 1000's of servers

Comment: THanks have book marked the link was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry and you don't need to change. Your former admin did a great job, disabling root and passwords is a good start for enhancing general security. Using only key authentification is safe. Usually keys won't become outdated, they are just stored in the filesystem and as long as they remain there, they'll work. You also don't need to worry to become locked out. If you have full control over the webservers, you always can give yourself root access just by modify the file `/etc/shadow` (activating root again). The only problem here would be, that you need to mount the filesystem with anohter OS instance. There are several ways to do this. One of the more easier ways is to use the initramfs-operating system layer or to use a bootable install image and use a shell.

If you really want to have a root password, I recommend to use a very very long password and set it up on all machines, print it out and enclose it into a safe. You can set a root password just by `sudo passwd`. This usually also activates the root user account. This password should only be known by a minimum amount of people, should not be stored on any computer system with internet access and should only be used in emergency.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ansible to centrally manage the ssh keys on those servers,might be overkill not sure.

https://medium.com/@chandrapal/managing-linux-users-ssh-keys-using-ansible-39ee2fc24c16

And maybe combine that with a solution like keeper security where you can share the ssh keys to only the people who need it.